# Algorithm to calculate maximum possible length of a String

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, set

Problem:

Given an array of strings arr. String s is a concatenation of a sub-sequence of arr which have unique characters.

Return the maximum possible length of s

Examples:

```
Input: arr = ["un","iq","ue"]
Output: 4
Explanation: All possible concatenations are "","un","iq","ue","uniq" and "ique".
Maximum length is 4.
```

```
Input: arr = ["cha","r","act","ers"]
Output: 6
Explanation: Possible solutions are "chaers" and "acters".
```

My solution:

```
var maxLength = function(arr) {
    if(!arr || arr.length === 0)    return 0;
    
    let word = "";
    arr.sort((a,b) => b.length - a.length);
    let set = new Set();
    
    const removeFromSet = (str) => {
        for(let i=0; i<str.length; i++) {
            set.delete(str[i]);
        }
    }
    
    const isInSet = (str) => {
        for(let i=0; i<str.length; i++) {
            if(set.has(str[i])) {
                removeFromSet(str.substring(0, i));
                return true;
            }
            else 
                set.add(str[i]);
        }
        return false
    }
    
    for(let i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
        if(!isInSet(arr[i])) {
            word += arr[i];
        }
    }
    
    return word.length;
};
```

It fails for the input: `["ab","cd","cde","cdef","efg","fgh","abxyz"]`
It should return 11, but my solution returns 9.

I know that my solution is calculating: "abxyzcdef" and it should be: "abxyzfghcde". Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Reference: https://leetcode.com/problems/maximum-length-of-a-concatenated-string-with-unique-characters/

Comment: I know it is a leetcode problem. Do you know what's wrong in my code?

Comment: Yes, the link is for people other than you who don't have context for the problem. I'll look at the code when I get a chance later on if nobody has answered, but it's a bit of a code dump as it stands. What do _you_ think is wrong with your code/what efforts have you made to isolate the problem? Please describe your approach/rationale here.

Answer (score 1):

Hole algorithm is recursivly, starting with only the string-array. If the second parameter str is not defined than it's setted to an empty strin (only at start).
Iterate through the string-array look if there is a builded string. If so than split the new teststring in chars and look if there exists at least one char (with [Array#some](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)) that is included in the builded string. If this condition is as well true than the string would not be contain unique chars so we can continue. Otherwise this is till now a possible sollution.
Now take the array and remove all the teststrings which have been tried (included the actual tested) because testing with them isn't usefull. Call the algorithm itself recursivly with shortened string-array and the string extended with the actual teststring.
Look if the length of the acual teststring plus the return value of recursiv call is greater than maximum than actualisize it.
After iterateing through all testrings from the array return the maximum length from an allowed string.

**Extended:** I check at start all strings with Array.filter for words with multiple same chars so e.g. 'abba' will not be tested.

```js
function maxLength(array, str) {
       if (str === undefined) {
           str = '';
           array = array.filter(elem => elem.split('').every((char, key) => !(elem.slice(key+1)).includes(char)));
    };
    array = array.filter(elem => elem.split('').every((char, key) => !(elem.slice(key+1)).includes(char)));
    let max=0;
    for (let i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
        let test= array[i];
        if (str.length && test.split('').some(char => str.includes(char))) {
             continue;
        } else {
            let len = test.length + maxLength(array.slice(i), str + test);
            if (len>max) max=len;
        }
    }
    return max;
}

console.log( maxLength(["un","iq","ue"]) );
console.log( maxLength(["cha","r","act","ers"]) );
console.log( maxLength(["ab","cd","cde","cdef","efg","fgh","abxyz"]) );
console.log( maxLength(["yy","bkhwmpbiisbldzknpm"]) );
```

Comment: You are right, I directly started and din't see your comment, so I didn't have a look to the LC. I will look for the code from the OP.

Comment: I tried to solve this and I misable failed. I upvote you because I think that your solution is so clean and so beutiful that deserve at least a prize. BRAVO :)

Comment: Thanks. I give you in an other answer an explanation why your solution don't works. But not how you can solve it ;).

Comment: It fails for the input: ["yy","bkhwmpbiisbldzknpm"]. The answer should be 0, your solution gives 20

Comment: @yTest532 myTest532 -  I extended it, now I first check all strings for multiple same chars and fiter them out.

Answer (score 0):

I found **your** **logical fault**: You only look straight forward and if one string not match you leave this one out and testing the next and go on like this.
But if one string matches you **never** look if possible another would be better.

**Explanation:**
I will explain it a little more. These are your sorted strings for testing:

```
["abxyz", "cdef", "cde", "efg", "fgh", "ab", "cd"]
```

You tried these combinations(first the tested good string and second your actual candidate) and afterwardes result for testing:

```
abxyz => ok
abxyz cdef => ok
abxyz cdef cde => false
abxyz cdef efg => false
abxyz cdef fgh => false
abxyz cdef ab => false
abxyz cdef cd => false
```

So your max-length is 9 (choose the first and the second string). But the solution `abxyz cde fgh` you don't take a look on it. For this you had to look instead of `cdef` for the shorter `cde` which is in combination with `fgh` the solution.
This is only the **explanation** why this don't work but **not** how you can **solve** it ;).

Comment: Thanks, understood. I will try to solve my solution.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I stuck with the same problem